# Usage of 'From' and 'Through'

Tags: prepositions, collocation

Should I say

> *looking **from** the window*

or

> *looking **through** the window*

to describe the landscape that lies beyond the window?

Comment: The view from my window is wider than the view through my window (from my desk).

Comment: You could look ***from*** an ***open*** window, but if you were looking ***through*** a window, that would usually imply looking *through the **glass** [of a **closed** window].*

Answer (score 1):

They're both acceptable.

*Looking from* puts more emphasis on the location of the looker, while *looking through* emphasizes that the looker and the thing they're looking at are on different sides of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Both are adequate to describe the activity you mention. Neither carries more import than the other.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, both would work but *looking through the window* makes the meaning very clear.

While *from* is used in this context by many, *through* really conveys the idea of looking through a medium, in this case the window's glass pane.

You can consider using *looking outside the window* as well. For instance,

"As I was looking outside the window, I saw a cat cross the street."

Results from Ngram for your reference-

[image: From vs Through]